# Anylogic: Queue timeout & condition

Tags: anylogic

In the default settings it is possible to set a time in the queue after which an agent leaves the queue via outTimeOut. However, only a fixed time can be entered in the corresponding field, e.g. 12 hours. Is there a possibility to link these 12 hours with a condition? In my case, the agent should only leave the queue after 12 hours via outTimeOut if a certain condition is also met. In my case, if a variable varIN == 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collect the time in queue statistics for each agent. Create a parameter called `entryTime`. When they enter the block, set `agent.entryTime=time();`

You can create an event that iterates through the queue every 1 second and removes the agents that meet your conditions from the queue (by using `remove(Agent agent)` function). That means if `(time()-agent.entryTime>12)&&(agent.varIN==1)`, you will remove that agent.

Loop will look like this:

```
for (int i=0; i< yourQueue.size(); i++) {
    YourAgentType currentAgent = ((YourAgentType)yourQueue.get(i));

   if ((time()-currentAgent.entryTime>12)&&(currentAgent.varIN==1)){
     yourQueue.remove(currentAgent);
}
}
```

Comment: Assuming `varIN` is a variable outside of the agent it is probably better to only trigger this event to start running as soon as the `varIN` variable is set to 1... and then have the event reschedule itself as log as `varIN == 1`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function (returning a double) to define and calculate the most complex logic you like. If you provide an argument of type Agent (or the specific agent type flowing through the blocks), it can even account for your agent characteristics.

In the queue block timeout, simply call the function.

Comment: @TRUESIM be careful with this option - the evaluation is dynamic but only for when the agent arrives. Meaning that if the conditions used in the function to calculate the timeout value changes the time the agent received when it entered the queue will not change. Thus if the agent enters the queue and `varIN == 0` and you tell it the time out is Infinite and then 1 second later `varIN == 1` and the timeout for all subsequent agents is 10, they will leave but that first agent will never leave the queue....